# How to get to Registrations of PrismApplication

Tags: unity-container, prism

In older UnityBootstrapper I had this:

```
                var reg = instance.Container.Registrations.First(r => type == r.RegisteredType);
reg.MappedToType
```

I want to get to the type that is registered for the certain interface and in new PrismApplication they haven't made it simple to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetContainer` on the container abstraction you receive from prism to get the actual container:

```
var reg = containerRegistry.GetContainer().Registrations.First(r => type == r.RegisteredType);
```

Comment: PrismApplication GetContainer() does not expose Registrations. UnityBootstrap does.

Comment: The `Container` property of the `UnityBootstrapper` just exposes the container. Same does the new `GetContainer` extension. `IUnityContainer` exposes the registrations, as seen in the source: https://github.com/unitycontainer/abstractions/blob/master/src/Abstracts/IUnityContainer.cs

Comment: I've looked in containerRegistry.GetContainer() before and couldn't find it, must've been some mess up with namespaces.